# Disable longPress action on mobile with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, web-applications

in this period,I make some new webApps, but I have a big problem with drag and drop.
I write a file manager in javascript, but when on mobile (smartphone, tablet andorid or iOs) I try to work drag and drop, the phone show me the longPress menu (on folder icon for examample) for copy url or image. 
there is some way in JS to disable longPress on mobile?

load image via css, isn't a valid solutions for me.

Comment: are you using jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```

Comment: Only for Apple devices: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout

Answer (score 1):

check the value of `navigator.userAgent` and compare with android|iphone|ipad  etc and in your java script you could do the following

```
function init() {
  onLongPress(document.getElementById('element'));
}

function onLongPress(node) {
  node.ontouchstart = nullEvent;
  node.ontouchend = nullEvent;
  node.ontouchcancel = nullEvent;
  node.ontouchmove = nullEvent;
}

function nullEvent(event) {
  var e = event || window.event;
  e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}
```